# npm native code always compiles

Tags: node.js, compilation, npm

I have a module that requires protobuf, which is written in c ( I think ). Every time I do an npm install it re-compiles the code whether it's there or not.  Not too big a deal except that it's huge and takes a while.  Is there anyway around this?